# Space Syntax Toolkit - How do unlinks (bridges/tunnels) work in a road centreline map?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Having read most of the papers/ books that about SpaceSyntax that contain the keyword "unlink" I still have not been able to pinpoint how unlinks (bridges/ tunnels) should be addressed within the SpaceSyntax Toolkit.

Literature on the subject (e.g. Introduction to Space Syntax in Urban Studies) seems to imply that unlinking is only applicable to axial maps (since it is only described in a chapter on axial maps).

For DepthmapX and Axial maps, it is a matter of activating the unlink tool, clicking one line and then another and a circle will appear to unlink the two. So this works on a per line basis.  https://www.spacesyntax.online/software-and-manuals/depthmap/urban-spatial-model/
[image]

In QGIS, however, the lines marked in yellow are unlinks and put on their own layer for unlinks. However, I still get the error 'multiplelines':
[image]

And when I split the unlink lines at the intersection with the centrelines layer (map tab) they will give the error 'sinlge line'.

Here too, there are errors for 'mulitple lines' for both ways to solve the intersection:
[image]

These error messages are described briefly within this document: https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/1490063/1/SSS10_Proceedings_148.pdf

So how exactly am I supposed to resolve the unlink errors? What are the conditions that need to be met for unlinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to stumble upon the answer here: https://github.com/SpaceGroupUCL/qgisSpaceSyntaxToolkit/issues/193, see:
[image]